# Is something on the IO logic board burnt or..?

Tags: hardware, charging, power, magsafe

yesterday, i plugged my macbook pro to charge, and my magsafe charger got a little burn where it connects to the magsafe charger (wall->magsafe). Now my macbook pro won't charge, no light, no nothing, but it still works perfectly. I tested it with a multimeter and indeed, no voltage and no current comming out the magsafe charger, burnt. Maybe that's from power fluctuations, don't know for sure. The magsafe port has no marks of burning or something. I tried to charge it with 2 different magsafe chargers, still nothing. Could something on the IO logic board be burnt or maybe some safety cautions kicked in?

Answer (score 1):

[Reset your System Management Controller](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295), based on Apple's instructions, to see if that kickstarts your charging subsystem.